# Amazon s3 policy grants access only to Vimeo api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, vimeo-api

Is it possible to grant access, via a policy, only to Vimeo api to download the private content into my bucket?

I am trying to create a videos platform with RoR 5 and I am using paperclip to upload the videos to my S3 account. To avoid incompatibility problems with the videos I want use Vimeo to transcode and hosting them (I think is a better option than the transcoding service in cloud).

So I have to use the Vimeo API to upload the videos to my Vimeo account and more specifically the option "Automatic (“pull”) uploads"

- [Developer / API Upload Videos](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos)

where I need to pass "A url to a video file accessible by Vimeo's servers.", a S3 url in my case. The problem is that I want to have private content in my S3 bucket, but so the vimeo API can't access to the video url.

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#automatic-pull-uploads this is the "pull" option to upload videos to Vimeo.

Comment: Alex, can you provide more information about what you wish to achieve, for those of us not familiar with Vimeo? Are you uploading from Vimeo to S3, or from S3 to Vimeo? How does Vimeo access S3? Does Vimeo authenticate when connecting to S3?

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, do pre-signed S3 urls work when submitted to the Vimeo API like this?  If they do, this is easy enough.

Comment: Hi I removed my answer I talked with AWS support and using the policy in that way is not possible. I just guessed that answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS S3 documentation, this is possible. Follow this link for details:
[Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4). However, I am not sure that api.vimeo.com is the name of the Vimeo server that pulls videos.